# Acceder a un array que esta dentro del constructor desde un evento

Tags: javascript

quiero llenar un array con los datos de un formulario, estas es accesible desde cualquier otra función, menos cuando disparo el evento me la da Undefined y me salta este error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at HTMLFormElement.addData (formController.js:40)

```
í class formController{

constructor(view){        


    this.view = view;
    this.init()
}

init(){
    this.form = this.view.getElementById('form')
    this.company= this.view.getElementById('company')
    this.student = this.view.getElementById('student')
    this.teacher = this.view.getElementById('teacher')
    this.allTravels = [];
    this.loadAddEvent()
}


loadAddEvent(){
    this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.addData);

}


addData(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const travel = {
        teacher : teacher.value,
        student: student.value,
        company: company.value,
    }

   this.allTravels.push(travel);
   console.log(this.allTravels)

 }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JavaScript, `this` se asigna **en el momento de la ejecución del código**, no durante su definición/declaración:

```
loadAddEvent( ) {
  this.form.addEventListener( 'submit', this.addData );
}
```

Crees que el evento se asagnará al enlace entre el `this` actual y su función `addData`. Sin embargo, **esto es falso**. El `this` se decidirá **al invocarse el evento**.

La solución más fácil: usa [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions), que **si fijan el `this`**:

```
loadAddEvent( ) {
  this.form.addEventListener( 'submit', dat => this.addData( dat ) );
}
```